# PHP crop image from base64_decode

Tags: php

i am generating a screen grab jpg using html2canvas from this code. However i cant target a particaular div so i am grabbing the entire screen.

```
$canvasImg = $_POST['img'];
$data = base64_decode($canvasImg);
$File = "z.jpg"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $data);  
fclose($Handle);
```

**question**: how can i crop the image?
this is my attampt

```
$canvasImg = $_POST['img'];
$image = base64_decode($canvasImg);
$dest_image = 'z.jpg';
$img = imagecreatetruecolor('200','150');
$org_img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
$ims = getimagesize($image);
imagecopy($img,$org_img, 0, 0, 20, 20, 200, 150);
imagejpeg($img,$dest_image,90);
imagedestroy($img);
```

but im getting a errors
`Warning: getimagesize(�PNG  ) [<a href='function.getimagesize'>function.getimagesize</a>]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument`

Comment: You are looking for imagecreatefromstring() http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: You are not passing an image into imagecreatefrompng(), there is some error with your image variable

Comment: re edited my question, implemented `imagecreatefromstring()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first param of `getimagesize($image);` must be the **image's filename.**

Comment: If you want to do this on the fly, then `imagesx($image)` and `imagesy($image)` are what you need, to return the x and y size values appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You want `imagecreatefromstring();`, not `imagecreatefrompng();`. This'll turn it into a PHP image object, which you can then output as a JPEG using `imagejpeg();`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem inlies that you are passing the buffer of the PNG to the function. Hence why you get the magic number of a PNG (89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a ---OR--- 0x89 "PNG" CR LF 0x1A LF). You need to save the file to a temp location and pass the location to getimagesize and such. Hence why they complain about a stream.

You could use `imagecreatefromstring(...)` which will take the buffer and output a handle to the resource.