# convert image 64X64 px after decoding base64 image in php

Tags: php, json

hi i am retriving a base64 encoded version of image and i have to stored it by cropping it to small size. now i am not able to crop the image please help me
my Code is as follow..
Please help me in cropping base 64 image

```
    $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $note['file']);
                $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
                $decodedFile = base64_decode($data);
$file = fopen($destination , 'wb');


if(!fwrite($file, $decodedFile)){
                //return("ERROR: can't save file to $destination");
                return '-1';
            }
                fclose($file);
```

Comment: try with $success = file_put_contents($destination, $decodedFile);

Comment: image is uploading properly but i have to crop the image in 64*64

Comment: So searching for "resize image php" or "crop image php" is more difficult than writing a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the gd library for create the image file from binary code:

```
function binaryToFile($binary_imagen, $width, $height, $new_name, $url_destiny) {

    try{
        //actual size
        $info    = getimagesizefromstring($binary_imagen);
        $old_width = $info[0];
        $old_height = $info[1];

        //new resource
        $resource = imagecreatefromstring($binary_imagen);

        $resource_copy  = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        imagealphablending( $resource_copy , false );
        imagesavealpha( $resource_copy , true );

        imagecopyresampled($resource_copy, $resource, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                   $width, $height, 
                   $old_width, $old_height);

        $url = $url_destiny."/".$new_name".png";
        $final = imagepng($resource_copy, $url, 9);

        imagedestroy($resource);
        imagedestroy($resource_copy);

        return 1;

    }catch (Exception $e) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your need but if it is some what like this you want to achieve then may be this will help you

[PHP crop image from base64_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787836/php-crop-image-from-base64-decode)